# Generating multiple strings with template literals

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to generate multiple strings with a template literal and an array variable.

For example, a template literal replaces an expression (a variable in this case) with its content in a string:

```
var = "world";
tpl = `Hello ${var}!`;
console.log(tpl);
// Hello world!
```

What I'd like to do is generate multiple strings if var contains an array. Example:

```
var = ["world", "earth", "space", "aliens"];
tpl = `Hello ${var}!`;
console.log(tpl);
// Hello world!
// Hello earth!
// Hello space!
// Hello aliens!
```

How would I be achieving this? If not possible with template literals, what would be the prefered method?

thanks!

Comment: var.map(it => \`Hello ${it}\`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best things you could do is a function:

```js
const input = ["world", "earth", "space", "aliens"];
const tpl = text => `Hello ${text}!`;
const log = x => console.log(x);
input.map(tpl).forEach(log);
```